i want to take multiple keys and concatenate them into a single key how would i do that in thingsboard
i want to send via MQTT something that needs values from many different keys concatenated together im not sure how to go about it
i tried a script in the rule chain and tried the behavior section in the widgets to make it happen, i wanted to try inside the downlink to find a function that would take the value of the telemetry without the message being sent to the downlink but so far have been unsuccessful

You could try using the "originator attributes" node. In it, you can select the telemetry/attribute keys you want, and they will be added to the message. Then, using the "script" node, you could capture the keys as follows and generate a new message from them.
Hope it helps!
Code to generate new key based on concatenated keys
Result
